# Implementing Worker in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, worker

I want to implement Worker in my project but it seems like I cannot directly import the class. I am working on my project without any extra libraries / SDK such as Flex, furthermore, I am working on Flash Professional. I've been researching about this matter for awhile so I understand how Worker class functions but I cannot figure out how to actually implement it. When I try to import the Worker class using the following line of code:

```
import flash.system.Worker;
```

It says there is no such class called Worker in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay due attention to the Flash Player version requirements for [`Worker`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html):

> **Runtime Versions:**     *Flash Player 11.4*, AIR 3.4

Are you sure you're targeting Flash Player 11.4? It is quite a recent version.

Comment: Dang it, mine is currently targetting 11.2. Thanks for that. But how can you target Flash Player > 11.4?

Comment: @EnglishMaster You can Google for instructions on how to add support for recent versions in CS6, or start using Flash CC (Creative Cloud).

Comment: Plus, does that mean I need both Flash Player 11.4 and AIR3.4?

Comment: @EnglishMaster You only need that version of AIR if you want to make an AIR application.